# Query for JSON[] type in postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a table in postgres which include a field with `json[]` datatype.
structure of stored data in this column is like this:

```
[{
    "sym": "BTC",
    "enn": "Bitcoin",
    "fan": "",
    "prc": 7284.46,
    "c24": -4.33,
    "mkc": 124460367747.02,
    "mkp": 0
}, {
    "sym": "ETH",
    "enn": "Ethereum",
    "fan": "",
    "prc": 571.735,
    "c24": -5.23,
    "mkc": 57166582578.235,
    "mkp": 0
}, {
    "sym": "XRP",
    "enn": "Ripple",
    "fan": "",
    "prc": 0.625291,
    "c24": -6.28,
    "mkc": 24539115471.842476,
    "mkp": 0
}, {
    "sym": "BCH",
    "enn": "Bitcoin Cash",
    "fan": "",
    "prc": 1034.65,
    "c24": -7.09,
    "mkc": 17771148400,
    "mkp": 0
}, {
    "sym": "EOS",
    "enn": "EOS",
    "fan": "",
    "prc": 13.2186,
    "c24": -7.95,
    "mkc": 11845841674.9512,
    "mkp": 0
}]
```

what I need is fetching json with specific `"sym"` key. like this:

```
{
    "sym": "BTC",
    "enn": "Bitcoin",
    "fan": "",
    "prc": 7284.46,
    "c24": -4.33,
    "mkc": 124460367747.02,
    "mkp": 0
}
```

I tried this:

```
select to_json(data)::json ->'sym'->'BTC'from my_table;
```

but it's not working. I know it's not working because my field is an array, not  `json` and tried this

```
select json_array_elements(to_json(data)::json->'sym'->'BTC') from my_table;
```

but it's not working too.
any help?

Comment: I think it would be easier if you stored a "json array" inside a simple `json` column. An array of JSONs doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-with.html)? There are certainly a dozen other ways to do the same, but I find CTEs quite elegant and easy to read.

```
WITH j AS (
SELECT json_array_elements('[{"sym":"BTC","enn":"Bitcoin","fan":"","prc":7284.46,"c24":-4.33,"mkc":124460367747.02,"mkp":0},{"sym":"ETH","enn":"Ethereum","fan":"","prc":571.735,"c24":-5.23,"mkc":57166582578.235,"mkp":0},{"sym":"XRP","enn":"Ripple","fan":"","prc":0.625291,"c24":-6.28,"mkc":24539115471.842476,"mkp":0},{"sym":"BCH","enn":"Bitcoin Cash","fan":"","prc":1034.65,"c24":-7.09,"mkc":17771148400,"mkp":0},{"sym":"EOS","enn":"EOS","fan":"","prc":13.2186,"c24":-7.95,"mkc":11845841674.9512,"mkp":0}]'::json) AS sym
)
SELECT *
FROM j
WHERE j.sym->>'sym'= 'BTC';

                                              sym                                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"sym":"BTC","enn":"Bitcoin","fan":"","prc":7284.46,"c24":-4.33,"mkc":124460367747.02,"mkp":0}
(1 Zeile)
```